# $\sin 2x = 1/2, 2x = 150, 390$. But why not 30?

Tags: trigonometry

$0<x<360$

So $\sin(2x) = \sin (30 + 360)$ or $\sin(2x) = \sin (180-30)$.

It derives from 
\begin{align*}
\sin x - \cos x & =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x -2\sin x \cos x & = \frac{1}{2}\\
2\sin x \cos x & = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

But why not $\sin (2x) = \sin (30)$ ? So $x = 15$.

The answer only $x = 75$ and $195$.

Comment: Yes, why not? What's stopping you? Who told you you shouldn't have $2x = 30^\circ$? Also, don't forget $540^\circ - 30^\circ$. And $720^\circ + 30^\circ$. And $900^\circ - 30^\circ$. And ... Not to mention the negative angles.

Comment: $x = 15º$ is also correct, but we also need the domain in order for your question to make sense.

Comment: If you want to type math enclose it between dollar signs $, i.e write \$0<x<360\$

Comment: How do you get from $\sin x-\cos x=\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ to $\sin(2x)=\frac12$?

Comment: By squaring you introduced extra solutions where $\sin x-\cos x=-\frac1{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\sin 2x = \frac12=\sin 30° \iff 2x=30°+k360° \quad \lor \quad2x=180°-30°+k360°$$

therefore all the solutions are in the form

- $x=15°+k180°=15°,15°\pm 180°,15°\pm360°,\ldots$
- $x=75°+k180°=75°,75°\pm 180°,75°\pm360°,\ldots$

and for the range $0°\le x <360°$ the solutions are $15°$, $75°$, $195°$, $255°$.